# Complex relational mysql query with sum

Tags: mysql, database, join, sum

I'm struggling to construct a mysql query. I need to obtain data from two tables:

```
Table cash
----------
id
income_money
cashdata_id
paymentterm
```

_

```
Table cash_data
------------
id
total
user
date
```

So `cash_data` holds the payments that need to be paid, and `cash` holds the registered payments that are already processed.
When a payment is marked as complete, the relevant row in `cash_data` is updated with the associated `user` ID and `date`.
The idea is to make a query from `cash_data` and check which payments have some income money paid but that are not marked as complete (i.e. doesn't have `user` and `date` fields data).
Okay, it was simple to here.
The problem is that there may be several `cash` table rows relating to one `cash_data` row and I have to select all `cash_data` rows, and then select the relational `cash` rows and sum the `cash.income_money` - because I need to compare `cash.total` with `cash.income_money`.

Comment: If the answers below haven't solved your problem, consider providing an sqlfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Query summing money:**

This also uses a left join to show rows that may not yet have payments.

```
SELECT cd.id,
       cd.total,
       sum(c.income_money) AS "Total Income"
FROM cash_data cd
LEFT JOIN cash c ON c.cashdata_id = cd.id
GROUP BY cd.id,
         cd.total;
```

**First query which is rather simple:**

```
select cd.id, cd.total, sum(c.income_money) as "Total Income" from
cash_data cd  left join cash c 
on c.cashdata_id = cd.id
group by cd.id, cd.total;
```

**SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/800b4/6**

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the two tables. Like this:

```
SELECT SUM(cash.income_money), cash_data.total, cash_data.id
FROM cash_data 
    JOIN cash ON cash.cashdata_id=cash_data.id
```

Comment: Don't see any group by... This will simply sum all amounts for everything. See: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/800b4/5 containing your original SQL as second query.